# Nestjs: Validate user password for signin - Error: data and salt arguments required

Tags: authentication, mongoose, nestjs, bcrypt, salt

I'm trying to validate user password and using nestjs, mongoose & bcrypt. I'm getting `Error: data and salt arguments required` when I entered wrong password. validatePassword function is to compare whether user password and hash is matched. Can anyone please let me know where I made the mistake?

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('Users') private usersModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  async signIn(authCredential: AuthCredentialDto) {
    const {username, password} = authCredential;
    const userFound = await this.usersModel.findOne({username});
    const user = new User();


    if (userFound && (await user.validatePassword(password))) {
      return user.username;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private async hashPassword(password: string, salt: string): Promise<string> {
    return bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
  }
}
```

**user.schema.ts**

```
export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop()
  id: string;

  @Prop({
    unique: true,
  })
  username: string;

  @Prop()
  password: string;

  @Prop()
  salt: string;

  async validatePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, this.salt);
    return hash === this.password;
  }
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

**auth.controller.ts**

```
  @Post('signin')
  @ApiOperation({
    operationId: 'signin user',
    summary: 'Create company profile',
  })
  async signIn(@Body(ValidationPipe) authCredentialDto: AuthCredentialDto) {
    return this.authService.signIn(authCredentialDto);
  }
```

Comment: the hash function doesn't get the salt properly

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using the bcrypt library, but only applicable if you absolutely do not have to store your salt separately from your password.
There is no need to store the salt externally when passing a number to the hash function. This will generate a salt with the number of rounds specified.
Instead of re-hashing the password you can then use bcrypt's compare function with just the plaintext and the hash with no need to first get the salt.

Answer (score 0):

Try bcrypt.compare function that not needs a salt.
Example of code that worked for me :

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User {
    @Prop()
    username: string;
    
    @Prop({required: true})
    password: string;

    checkPassword: Function;
}

UserSchema.methods.checkPassword = function(attempt, callback) {
    let user = <UserDocument>this;   
    bcrypt.compare(attempt, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, isMatch);
    }); 
};
```